# How Docx4j interprets css

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I'm soon tearing my hair off but I'm really struggling with how docx4j interprets CSS when converting xhtml to a docx-file.

I've tried googling and I keep getting back to reading the sourcecode for the entire project in order to figure ut out.

For example I found out that font-sizes are only interpreted when in `pt` and not in `px, em` or any of the other sizes. And that by [reading this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.docx4j/docx4j/2.7.1/org/docx4j/model/properties/run/FontSize.java)

Also, if anyone could be so kind as to help me with `font-face` which just doesn't seem to work.

Is there anyone out here that can explain how or has any documentation as to how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclosure: I wrote the relevant docx4j code **

There are two parts to it.

The first is Flying Saucer / XHTML Renderer.

The second is the code in docx4j which converts what it gets from Flying Saucer to WordML.

As you've discovered, there are some things which docx4j doesn't convert yet (font face being one of them).  Not because they are particularly hard, but just because our priorities have been elsewhere.  You are welcome to add whatever you need and contribute a patch.

For simple stuff like you mention, the starting point is the addRunProperties method at line 1327 of XHTMLImporter.  There you can see the CSSValue objects provided by Flying Saucer.  I presume you've found the docx4j source code on GitHub.

Comment: Yep, I've cloned the repo and started working on implementing the html things I need, will submit a pull request when done. :) Thanks for the info. If you have any nice resources that would be optimal to read to further help out I would kindly accept them ^_^! Thanks!

Comment: I've successfully patched the font-family css property and it works like a charm! :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction in the end! :D Will supply a patch for it when I written some more tests for it! :)

Comment: That sounds great.  Good to see the open source process working :-)

Comment: Hi limelights and JasonPlutext. I am also trying to use font-family in converting html to docx. Was this ever folded into the main branch or is the only place which has this code https://github.com/limelights/docx4j?

Comment: Please see http://www.docx4java.org/forums/xhtml-import-f28/problem-with-fonts-t1849.html